# collocation for the noun "quote"

Tags: collocation

I was wondering how we use the noun "quote" in a sentence. Specifically, what verbs should we use after it? Can we use the verb say as in:

> A quote says, "Gender equality is more than a goal in itself."

Comment: That seems perfectly acceptable to me. You can also use *contains*, but that suggests that there's significantly more to the quote, and this is just part of it.

Comment: IMHO, a quote does not *say*.  A *person* may say something, and you may quote it.

Comment: For what it's worth (and it's not likely worth much), "quote" is a verb, whereas " quotation" is a noun. You can quote a person, but the words you quote comprise a quotation.

Comment: @rhetorician *Quote* is both a verb and a noun.

Comment: @Michael.hor257k: That may be so, but I'll continue to introduce the words of a famous (or otherwise) person as a quotation. So there! (Just kidding--about the "so there," that is). Don

Comment: i in fact understand that a quote doesn't say, yet I couldn't find the right word to introduce the actual quote. Besides, I heard ppl say, " a saying says..." I guess it is alright. Anyway, I do hope you can give some examples that the content of the quote is mentioned. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I feel it would sound more correct and specific to write who said the quote.

> [Person] (once) [wrote/said], "Gender equality is more than a goal in itself."

As a side note: I would shy away from the use of "once" here- "[Person] once said" sounds cliché.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking you can't use that, because a quote doesn't literally speak, but is passive. Figuratively speaking, you have the poetic freedom to use metaphors. Simpler (not better) to say is: *to be*.

The problem is however easily avoided, because quotes are already identified as such from an attribution, that has to be in context of the quote; otherwise direct speech quotation would be a mistake. I mean, I would try to conjoin your given example and the declaration which you would have linked back to from your example.

Comment: -1 Articles, books, magazines, newspapers, etc don't "literally speak" either, yet it's fine to say that any of them *says....*

Comment: @Clare, as I said, that's perfectly fine. I understand it as a contraction of a longer text that should include the acting person, who literally speaks. I've also heard: "*the quote reads*".